# recursive pCall function

Tags: c++, recursion, lua

I have a situation where a lua_pcall can sometimes be called recursively.  The recursive call does not work as expected.  I think it is because the 2nd call  still has the state of the previous lua_pcall.  The stack can still contain variables of the first lua_pcall, not to mention all the other internal variables that lua may use inside lua_State.

My setup is as follows..

```
class LuaObject
{
    public:

    lua_State* m_pLuaState;

    void Execute
    {
        //push processed script
        lua_pushvalue( m_pLuaState , -1 );

        //now run it
        int iStatus = lua_pcall( m_pLuaState, 0, 1, 0 );

        //remove the return value from the stack
        lua_pop( m_pLuaState, 1 );
    }
}
```

So, given the above setup.  LuaObject::Execute() can be called and then inside, it could call the same LuaObject::Execute(), which will run the lua_pcall with the same lua_State as the previous pcall.  Should I somehow ensure that m_pLuaState is prepared before each recursive call? 
 Or should I create a new lua_State for each lua_pcall?  I feel that preparing the same m_pLuaState is the correct way, but how do i do it?  Maybe push the lua_TFunction from when this script was processed onto the stack?

Comment: TGhat's apparently not C, but C++. Use the corect language tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problems with recursive calls, as long as you don't `yield` across such calls. Yielding is using `longjmp`, so it breaks the chain of calls, but that doesn't apply to regular `lua_pcall` uses.

Try this example (tested with Lua 5.2), there's function `foo`, calling native function `bar` which in turn calls `foo` again, decrementing the counter. No special actions are required to handle recursive calls.

```
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bar(lua_State* L)
{
    int num = lua_tointeger(L, 1);
    printf("bar: %d\n", num);
    if(num>0)
    {
        // call foo with decremented iteration count
        lua_getglobal(L, "foo");
        lua_pushinteger(L, num-1);
        lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    lua_pushcfunction(L, bar);
    lua_setglobal(L, "bar");

    luaL_dostring(L, "function foo(x)\n"
                     "  print(\"foo: \"..x)\n"
                     "  bar(x)\n"
                     "end\n");

    // call foo with 7 as iterations count
    lua_getglobal(L, "foo");
    lua_pushinteger(L, 7);
    lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0);
    lua_pop(L, 1);

    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

Whatever is wrong in your case (not working as expected, etc) might be related to your scripts and logic behind it, and not to the fact that the calls are recursive.

Comment: awesome.  The fact that "no special actions are required" helps alot.  It looks like the main difference from the example you provided and my code, is that I don't have the "lua function" on the stack when I recursively call pcall.  I'll try that to see if it cleans me up. tx!